# Send email with Ajax in Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

i an new to wordpress theme development, i need to send an email with ajax/PHP in wordpress

```
var dataString =    'name=' + name + 
        '&email=' + email + 
        '&contact=' + contact + 
        '&technology=' + technology +
        '&budget=' + budget +
        '&details=' + details;          

   alert(dataString);


   $.ajax({  
   type: "POST",  
   url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/qoute-sent.php",  
   data: {name:'anas', Email: 'anas@yahoo.com'},
   datatype: "html",  
   success: function() {  
   alert(sent);
   }
```

all the code work till `alert(dataString);` but after that ajax does not works....

this is my php file code

```
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
   // $contact=$_POST['contact'];
   //$technology=$_POST['technology'];
  // $budget=$_POST['budget'];
  //$details=$_POST['details'];

   //-------------for email setup----------------------------
   $to = "stylegurupk@gmail.com";
   //------------------------------------------
   $message = " \n " .

   "Name ".$name." \n " .
   "Email : ".$email." \n " ;

    //---------------------------------- 
    $subject = "MWM Qoute Request"; 
    $headers =  'From: '.$email . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$to . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    //echo "TO : ".$to."<br>";
    //echo "FROM : ".$email."<br>";
    //echo "<br>".$message;
    mail($to, $subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Not sure `datatype: "html"` works, can you use $_POST to retrieve data posted in this way? Anyone? Also `datatype` should be `dataType` i think.

Comment: This is a possible solution and while it doesn't use any "code" it does offer a lot of flexibility.  I would use a plugin called Contact Form 7.  I know this doesn't really answer your question and you may just want to learn to program within php which I totally understand but if you ever need a quick contact form I would really recommend Contact Form 7

Answer (score 0):

WordPress provides functionality and hooks to develop with AJAX to make it really easy. See [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

You should also check out [wp_mail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) for sending emails.

Remember that WordPress loads jQuery in noconflict mode, so your $ selector's should be 'jQuery'.

To prevent abuse you should consider adding a nonce to your script. WordPress handles that too :) See [wp_create_nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_nonce).

I think [this is a good reference article](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) once you have the bones in places

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/qoute-sent.php",
```

Should the URL be "quote-sent.php"? Just checking.

Also, have you set up the AJAX actions for WP? It won't work without them. I'd generally do something like:

```
<?php
    function my_send_email(){
        doStuff(); // etc..
        echo 'sent!';
        die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_my_send_email', 'my_send_email');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_send_email', 'my_send_email');
?>
```

Like Mark said, I'd also recommend using wp_mail.

Comment: Good! Was worried it was a typo. But the 2nd part... do you have AJAX actions in place?